# jspm config.js using system, not able to import Highmaps... (works fine with cjs)

Tags: highcharts, angular, jspm, highmaps

so this snippet works great when I use commonjs on my config.js

```
import * as Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';
Ng2Highcharts(Highcharts);
```

but as soon as I switch to system with the following import:

```
import * as Ng2Highcharts from 'highcharts/modules/map';
Ng2Highcharts.default(Highcharts)
```

I get an error of :

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: x[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a constructor
  ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
```

not sure why config.js switching from cjs to system breaks this,

Thanks

Sean

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: yes, switched to google maps :) is what I did